# how can display only month and year in DateTimePicker control

Tags: c#, winforms

How can display only month and year in `DateTimePicker` in WinForms?
I want the value like `January 2013`.

Comment: Calendar? Do you mean `DateTimePicker`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need three steps to modify display format of `DateTimePicker`:

- Set `Format` property to `DateTimePickerFormat.Custom`
- Set `CustomFormat` property to `"MMMM yyyy"`
- Assign `Value`

Now assigned date will be displayed in format `January 2013`.

Comment: this works for me but only one issue is that on click this display date on calender . That i dont want to display

Comment: @A.Goutam set `ShowUpDown` to `true`

Answer (score -2):

you can use this code, but it gives numbers format only:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

string s = now.ToString("MM-yy");
```

print s -> 03 13

Comment: but how can i display Month and Year on Winform

Comment: What do you mean? be more specific. what winform object would you like to use?

Comment: his asking how to only view month/year in "datetimepicker" control, not "datetime".